# Trying to create a Mongo Express container from instructions

Tags: docker, mongo-express

I am using the documentation on the [mongo-express page in Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express) to create my container. I used the command:

```bash
$ docker run --network some-network -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=some-mongo -p 8081:8081 mongo-express
```

Now I assume that this is supposed to work as is, but I keep getting the error:

```
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://some-mongo:27017/"
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - how are you running the Mongo container you're trying to connect it to?

Comment: I am using the instructions that on https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express, and I am using a combination of docker desktop and CMD docker commands. Not sure what more I can provide.

Comment: You could provide _what I asked for_ - information about the DB you're trying to connect the admin panel to. Why you think it _should_ be able to access `mongodb://some-mongo:27017`, does it _actually exist_. Generally you have to replace the placeholder dummy data in the docs with information pertinent to your actual setup.

Comment: OK so first I am new to dockers and containers. So I am just following instructions i get on dockerhub. I assumed that this was a simple download image, run container, open browser and see interface. This does not happen. I get what you are saying and had I another container with a database I would reply as you wanted but I am literally just doing what I see on the page. Maybe you can have a bit of patience and see what I am saying? Or not. Thanks for the help otherwise

Comment: Per the page you linkL _"mongo-express is a web-based MongoDB admin interface"_. It is **just** an admin interface. If you don't have an actual DB to connect it to you want to administer, which you'd configure via `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER` _et al._, it's no use to you. This isn't anything to do with Docker or containers, new to them or otherwise - it's the nature of that tool in general, which [doesn't have to be run in Docker](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express#usage-npm--cli) (neither does Mongo itself, for that matter).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256497/discussion-between-arklight-dev-and-jonrsharpe).